# Creating a database when installing an SAP Business One Add on

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sapb1

I am creating an SAP Business One add-on payroll application - EIMPayroll. I have created an .ard file and I am able to install this add-on in SAP, ie, going to the add on manager and registering the payroll application using the .exe and .ard files.

However, on the machine that I install this add-on on, I have to manually import/create the Microsoft SQL server database "Eim_payroll.bak" on the computer for this add-on to run.

My question is, is there a way I can write the sql query to create the database and tables needed to run this application on a C# file and then package it together into the ard file such that it installs when I install the add-on in SAP?

I create the ard file using Visual Studio 2010 and using the SAP B1 AddOnInstaller .NET Wizard. My add-on is in C#.

Any help will be appreciated, including links on examples of how this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are asking. I believe you want to create user tables and user defined fields when registering the add-on in SAP.

Try this, it may work. For creating tables:

```
ousertable = ocompany.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oUserTables)
ousertable.TableName = "OEMP"
ousertable.TableDescription = "Employee Header"
lretcode = ousertable.Add
If lretcode 0 Then
ocompany.GetLastError(lerrcode, serrmsg)
sbo_application.MessageBox(serrmsg)
End If
```

For creating table fields:

```
ouserfield = ocompany.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oUserFields)
ouserfield.TableName = "@OEMP"
ouserfield.Name = "empid"
ouserfield.EditSize = "5"
ouserfield.Type = SAPbobsCOM.BoFieldTypes.db_Numeric
ouserfield.Description = "Employee id"
lretcode = ouserfield.Add
If lretcode 0 Then
ocompany.GetLastError(lerrcode, serrmsg)
sbo_application.MessageBox(serrmsg)
End If
```

Cheers

Comment: Where I need to call the add table? In which addon layer I need to add my code?